# How to make a list of variables the header for a data frame [R]

Tags: r, multiple-columns, names

I have a data frame with no headers. It has 561 columns.
It has the generic headers like so

```
V1 V2 ... V561
```

I also have a txt. file that has all of the variable names for that data frame. They are all in one column, like so:

```
1 tBodyAcc-mean()-X   
2 tBodyAcc-mean()-Y   
3 tBodyAcc-mean()-Z  
...  
561 angle(Z,gravityMean)
```

How would I go about reading that file in and putting all those variables as the column names for the original dataset?

Comment: read the .txt file in as a dataframe df1, then use `names(your_dataframe) <- df1[,1]`

Comment: and you can import txt file as `txt <- read.delim("temp.txt", header = FALSE)`, and you replace temp.txt with your file.